# After update - crash com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.8

Tags: java, android, gradle

my dependencies:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
```

but still:
Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5208000 but found 5089036

how is this possible?

UPDATE this work:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

or

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
```

or

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'`

Comment: Have you tried telling gradle to refresh dependencies?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Play Services version 5.2.08 too recent for my device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198291/google-play-services-version-5-2-08-too-recent-for-my-device)

Comment: Your update works perfect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update Google Play Services from Play store on you device, if you don't see any update wait until comes out

[Play Store - Google Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms)

Alternatively search on Google and installed the new apk or use an older version like 5.0.77 or 5.0.89

Comment: with 5.0.89 work nice.
the problem is a version of  Google Play Services from Play store on the device?
i have rooted nexus 7 4.4.3 i dont see any update in Google store

Comment: exactly, if you don't see updates on Google Play you need to wait for that or use precedent version in app

Comment: Google Play Services 5.2 aren't rolled out yet. You shouldn't use this version for development unless you are developing apps which use the preview of Google Fit. Use version 5.0.89 as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 34):

Change the **Google Play Service** version in your **build.gradle** to the version on your device or emulator.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

Comment: Iam new to studio.Does this means that i have to change  Google Play Service version in  build.gradle every time?

Answer (score 4):

The version you are looking for is 5.2.08.

> Android Studio will automatically offer to upgrade it to the new version. However, due to a bug, it drops the leading zero in "08", which means it replaces the dependency with "5.2.8" instead of "5.2.08" which does not work. To fix this, edit the dependency to read "5.2.08" instead of "5.2.8"

This will work:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
```

source: http://tools.android.com/knownissues

Comment: At my HTC one m8 - Google Play Edition (KK 4.4.4) it wouldn't. PlayStore is on newest version. Strange feelings -.-

Answer (score 1):

For people who suffer from this issue but are not able to make the other work - my issue was that I installed Google Play 5.2.08 in my gradle file (compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08') because 5.0.77 wasn't working.

1. I loaded the app onto my phone and it didn't work,
2. I had the latest update (that I could get on my phone - Android 4.4.2) of google play so telling me to update didn't give me any options
3. I ended up just needing to update my  gradle file to the latest **compatible** googlePlay, in my case version 5.0.89.
   So find out what version

Answer (score 1):

You can now use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with
For `Gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
```

For `Eclipse`:

Add as library:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_5077000_r18.zip

If above did not work, try to use older playstore service version of android playstore client.

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_4132530_r14.zip

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_4242030_r15.zip

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_4323030_r16.zip

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_5077000_r18.zip

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_5089000_r19.zip

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_6171000_r21.zip