# Always getting message update google play service while check google play service in startup application

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have develop an application that have functionality of google cloud messaging so i am used latest google play service and as development tool is android studio so i get code for gcm from android developer site http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html and then i checked google play services available or not on start up of application

```
 public boolean checkPlayServices(Activity activity) {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            activity.finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

but it always return this message "This app wont run unless you update Google play services
[image]

Comment: I have similar problem. Do you found solution?

upd: This works for me. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198291/google-play-services-version-5-2-08-too-recent-for-my-device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198291/google-play-services-version-5-2-08-too-recent-for-my-device)