# "This app won't run until you update Google Play Services" GameBaseUtils

Tags: android

I'm trying to integrate Games in my application using BaseGameUtils. Everything look OK but when I run the app I get the message "This app won't run until you update Google Play Services", when I click the Update button, the Play Store opens in the Google Play Services page, but I only can "Open" or "Uninstall" because it is updated. I tried reinstalling but does not work.

EDIT: I get this message from Logcat "GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5208000 but found 5089010" but I'm using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'

Comment: Did you read this? <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar>

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your answer. I read the post but it is referencing problems using emulator, my problem occurs with physical phones.

Comment: I have the same problem. The only difference is that the version found in my devices is 5089036,

Comment: possible duplicate of [After update - crash com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203415/after-update-crash-com-google-android-gmsplay-services5-2-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue requiring version 5.0.+ of the Google Play Services. For that, I changed both the file build.gradle, both in my app module and in the BaseGameUtils module, from:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+'
```

These questions mention the same issue:

[Google Play Services version 5.2.08 too recent for my device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198291/google-play-services-version-5-2-08-too-recent-for-my-device)

[After update - crash com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203415/after-update-crash-com-google-android-gmsplay-services5-2-8)